# <rich:calendar> client side disable weekends

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have following xhtml file vith `rich:calendar` and I'm trying to disable some days [using this example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/calendar.jsf?tab=clientSideCustomization). But javascript function is never called. I don't know why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html ... >

<f:view locale="en">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function isDayEnabled(day){
      var date = new Date(day.date);
      return (date.getDay() == 6); 
    }
    function getDisabledStyle(day){
      if (!isDayEnabled(day)) return 'rich-calendar-boundary-dates disabledDay';
    }
  </script>

<h:head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .disabledDay { background-color:gray; }
 </style>
</h:head>

<h:body> 
 <div id="workspace">
  <h:form id="form">
   <h:outputText value="Datum: " />
   <rich:calendar mode="ajax" id="calendar"
    isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled();" dayStyleClass="getDisabledStyle();">                   
   </rich:calendar>
....
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the showcase example shows, you need to specify the sole function *name*. Remove the parentheses.

```
<rich:calendar mode="ajax" id="calendar"
    isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled" dayStyleClass="getDisabledStyle">
```

Or when you're *actually* using RichFaces 4.0, then you need to check a [different showcase site](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=clientStylingDisablement&skin=blueSky).

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:outputStylesheet>
        .everyThirdDay {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .weekendBold {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
        }
    </h:outputStylesheet>
    <h:outputScript>
        var curDt = new Date();
        function disablementFunction(day){
            if (day.isWeekend) return false;
            if (curDt==undefined){
                curDt = day.date.getDate();
            }
            if (curDt.getTime() - day.date.getTime() &lt; 0) return true; else return false; 
        }
        function disabledClassesProv(day){
            if (curDt.getTime() - day.date.getTime() &gt;= 0) return 'rf-cal-boundary-day';
            var res = '';
            if (day.isWeekend) res+='weekendBold ';
            if (day.day%3==0) res+='everyThirdDay';
            return res;
        }
    </h:outputScript>
    <rich:calendar dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction"
        dayClassFunction="disabledClassesProv" boundaryDatesMode="scroll" />
</ui:composition>
```

The attributes are renamed to `dayDisableFunction` and `dayClassFunction`.

Comment: Thank you, I've also found this example before. But It doesn't work even if I simply copy it to xhtml a start it. I can't click on calendar button, it's disabled..

Comment: Are you using RF 3.3 or 4.0? And do you realize that this is an include template (look at `<ui:composition>`!) which should be included by `<ui:include>` in a master template which in turn has a `<h:head>` so that all the proper styles and scripts will be added automatically?

Comment: RF4.0. Aha, i didn't know it, i'm still using html tag :( I'll take a look on it deeper. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can just copy the piece between `<ui:composition>` and `</ui:composition>` into your page. The RF 4.0 showcase examples are just presented as include template files.

Comment: In principal I have two files now - i'm opening file `index.xhtml` with only one tag (`<ui:composition>` including template `test.xhtml` and `xmlns:ui`), and the original `test.xhtml` file which includes reference to `style.css` and `test.js` file with javaScript functions and `<rich:calendar>`. I'm sure it's not correct use of this stuff, but it's working completelly!